# Best Api.ai entity to describe duration

Tags: entities, dialogflow-es

I wanted to ask if anyone knows the best Api.ai entity to describe a duration with different ways.

Example:

- Do the task in 30 min
- Do the task in 1 hour and 30 min
- Do the task    from 1:10 pm to 2:20 pm

Unfortunately the `@sys.duration` entities takes only one unit and `@sys.periode` doesn't respond to the first two examples.

Thanks!

Comment: You can set the @sys.period on the first 2 examples. Go and highlight them and choose it from the pop-up menu...

Comment: @Momin Thank you! could you tell me what's wrong with my post to correct it for the future?

Comment: @IdoGreen Could you clarify your answer more, please? Do I choose `@sys.period` and then configure this choice?

Comment: Sure. You should type more examples and highlight them with the mouse. Than, API.AI will bring a pop-up dialog and let you choose which entity you wish to assign to what you just 'marked' - If you show it the few variations and assigned them to sys.periode it should work.